# I can't find ifort exe when I install intel with conda

Tags: ubuntu, installation, conda, intel-fortran

I installed the Fortran compiler with conda the following comment:
**conda install -c anaconda intel-fortran-rt**.
I want to use ifort but I can't find its path and I encountered the following comment:
**Command 'ifort' not found**

Answer (score 0):

The name of the packsge -rt suggest that this is a package for *runtime libraries*, libraries necessary to run programs compiled by the Intel compiler. See more in the [package description](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/intel-fortran-rt).

It is not supposed to contain the whole compiler package. Install Intel OneAPI from the Intel webpage to get the complete distribution.

Even after the instalation of the complete distribution you need to run the `setvars` configuration script to be able to run ifort from the command line.